# ionic serve WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:53703/' failed: net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: ionic3

when I tried to start Ionic 3 app with ionic serve its giving me the below error in chrome

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:53703/' failed: net::ERR_FAILED
```

I didn't update any thing (node, npm, ionic cli) in my system.it suddenly started throwing error

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.6 (C:\Users\jmzw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.6
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : windows 6.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v8.10.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to delete node_modules folder and run npm install
then do 
`ionic serve`